# Ruby on Rails: is it possible to access multi posgtgresql databases of heroku with one app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku-postgres

I have two Rails apps in Heroku with Postgresql Databases.
Noiw i want to  access those two databases with one app ony.

Is it Possible?

Comment: You should explain why you want to use multiple database. Also please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825844/multiple-databases-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

You can share one app database with other (with your own risk) like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981508/share-database-between-2-apps-in-heroku). If you want multiple database connection in single rails app, you can try (with your own risk) this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238915/heroku-follow-how-to-handle-multiple-databases-in-a-rails-app)