# Can we connect to multiple database connections after the Application has been deployed to production on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am new to Rails and need some help on this! 
Can we connect to a local database and production database simultaneously after the project has been deployed to production ??

for example : My application when deployed to production, with a click of a button on the page, it should toggle between the usage of production database and the user's local database.Is that possible ?

Thanks!

Comment: just look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122508/connecting-rails-3-1-with-multiple-databases

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, there are some clues in the comments here:

- [ActiveRecord/Base/connection](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/connection)
- [ActiveRecord/Base/establish_connection/class](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/establish_connection/class)
- [Useful explanation of establish_connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122508/connecting-rails-3-1-with-multiple-databases)

And a more comprehensive guide here:

- [dynamic-database-switching-rails-how-to-do-it](http://ryanstenhouse.eu/tutorials/2010/02/07/dynamic-database-switching-rails-how-to-do-it/)

But it's a bit of a faff - why do you need to do this, maybe there is another way to achieve what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.I want my application to be pluggable.... like when a user wants to use his local database specific to his need. I should be able to let the user do that...

Comment: How do I disconnect from production database while connecting to local database (because while querying, I think the app will try to fetch entries from both the connections?)and then when I press some button how do i connect back to production database again. Thanks a lot for the information!