# Rails tableless model but still want to acess DB and export some data to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to create a Rails application that will access a Database (namely two different databases) and do some comparing. Then i went that data spit back out into the view for users to see.

This application will not create or save any data anywhere.

All i want is for user to pick a date and then get data from the databases based on this workflow.

I have been trying tableless models all morning, but i am a bit stuck.

For example, should i have my model still be able to access the database but not allow any create methods?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can have rails working with different connections at each time and you can also have different connections customized for each model.

From the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html):

> Connection to multiple databases in different models
>
> Connections are usually created through
>   ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection and retrieved by
>   ActiveRecord::Base.connection. All classes inheriting from
>   ActiveRecord::Base will use this connection. But you can also set a
>   class-specific connection. For example, if Course is an
>   ActiveRecord::Base, but resides in a different database, you can just
>   say Course.establish_connection and Course and all of its subclasses
>   will use this connection instead.
>
> This feature is implemented by keeping a connection pool in
>   ActiveRecord::Base that is a Hash indexed by the class. If a
>   connection is requested, the retrieve_connection method will go up the
>   class-hierarchy until a connection is found in the connection pool.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311199/connecting-to-multiple-databases-in-ruby-on-rails) will help you to do it in code.