# Unable to Switch Mysql database connection dynamically after login in rails 4?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, rails-activerecord

I am having different databases for each signup and there is one common Global database for sign in authentication..

What i need is After Logged in, user should be switched to other database and that switched database should be used throughout application until user logged out.

Right now when i switch database after logged in, it does connection with default database(database.yml) on every controller request.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting to multiple databases in ruby on rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311199/connecting-to-multiple-databases-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 2):

Install the pg gem in your Gemfile

gem 'pg'

change the database.yml file to use your database ex.

adapter: postgresql
database: db_name
pool:
timeout:
host: localhost
username: username
password: password
set your db_name, username, and password same as postgresql database.

Have fun..

Comment: Hello  vishal dhanopia, Thanks for your reply. But i have used mysql database.. so is it possible for Mysql?