# Simultaneous connection to multiple databases using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to establish connection to multitple databases at the same time using the gem 'active_record'

i am using below code to achieve that:

```
require 'active_record'

conn1 = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
        :adapter => 'oracle_enhanced',
        :database => "//db1",
        :username => 'user1',
        :password => 'pwd1'
    )
a = conn1.connection.exec_query("select N_WF_NIE from COMBINED")
puts a

conn2 = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
        :adapter => 'oracle_enhanced',
        :database => "db2",
        :username => 'user2',
        :password => 'pwd2'
    )
b = conn2.connection.exec_query("select MSLNN from PICAAMISC")
puts b
```

Now further in the script when I use the first connection(`conn1`) that is nullified and the below query does not return any result.

```
c = conn1.connection.exec_query("select N_NIE from AGG")
puts c
```

I want to make sure that both my connections are active at the same time so that I can use any of the connection in the script if required, is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Why do you want to achieve this ? Do you want to create a Multitenancy app ? Don't you have any better options ?

Comment: @XavM, suppose I have 2 databases and I want to compare the schema of both ,for  example tables, columns, data etc. and that too one by one. so for all the cases i establish connection to one db then another and then compare both, then again for other test i again need to establish connection.

i wanted to create connection one time only and then use the same in the script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting Rails 3.1 with Multiple Databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122508/connecting-rails-3-1-with-multiple-databases)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122508/connecting-rails-3-1-with-multiple-databases and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311199/connecting-to-multiple-databases-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: @Nick Roz:He already uses establish_connection method, like in these posts. 
'@s c: I'm not really sure you can have simultaneous connection with two different db. You could store schema of one db and then connect to the second one to compare each other

Comment: @NickRoz, No above Links doesn't help in my case, Please let me know if there is any other way out

Comment: Try https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus