# How do I connect multiple databases in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby, database, postgresql

I am trying to connect multiple databases in my rails app one as a primary and the other as a secondary. This is what I have in my database.yml

```
# SQLite version 3.x 
# gem install sqlite3 
# 
# Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile 
# gem 'sqlite3' 
# 
# development: 
# adapter: postgresql 
# database: martin_development 
# username: 
# password: 
# pool: 5 
# timeout: 5000 


development: 
adapter: sqlserver 
host: 
port: 1433 
database: 
username: 
password:
```

I left out some data for obvious reasons but the sqlserver is connected but I lost all my data from the postgresql database and I need it as well because it holds separate data for the blog and author logins et cetera. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to multiple databases in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311199/connecting-to-multiple-databases-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: You can check this article for more detail: http://www.blrice.net/blog/2016/04/09/one-rails-app-with-many-databases/