# can't see tables in specific database using rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In my case.
I have use two different databases in my single application. 
One is mysql and another one is sqlsever.

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables

Using this command i have see all table in my mysql database tables. 
But i don't know the command to see specific database table using rails console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
a=ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter=> "adapter_name",
  :encoding=> "utf8",
  :reconnect=> "false",
  :database=> "db_name",
  :pool=> "5",
  :username=> "xxxx",
  :password=> "xxxxxxx",
  :host=>"xx.xx.xx.xx"
)

a.connection.tables
```

Comment: thank for reply but i got error..ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("#{development_sec}").connection.tables
NameError: undefined local variable or method `development_sec' for main:Object

Comment: have you added database configuration in database.yml file ?

Comment: this is my database.yml file development_sec:
  mode: dblib
  adapter: sqlserver
  dataserver: 123.201.**.***
  database: ZKA
  username: sa
  password: pass

Comment: i have done all this things already.. but still same error is  occurring. "NameError: undefined local variable or method `development_sec' for main:Object"

Comment: @SantoshKumbhar accept my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47448715/how-to-access-multiple-databases-in-single-rails-application-in-rails-4/47448896#47448896

Comment: @SantoshKumbhar vote my answer also if it works for you. Thanks

Comment: How do we find the host?

Answer (score 0):

The bellow code returns array of all tables present in particular database connection mentioned in the database.yml.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(Rails.configuration.database_configuration["#{other_connection_name}"]).connection.tables
```

Where **other_connection_name** is the name of connection to DB mentioned in database.yml.

For example database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  collation: utf8_bin
  reconnect: true
  database: dev_schema
  pool: 5
  username: xxx
  password: xxxx
  host: localhost

otherconnection:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  collation: utf8_bin
  reconnect: true
  database: gbl_schema
  pool: 5
  username: xxx
  password: xxx
  host: localhost
```

For above **database.yml** we use bellow code to retrieve all tables present in **dev_schema** and **gbl_schema** respectively

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(Rails.configuration.database_configuration["development"]).connection.tables
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(Rails.configuration.database_configuration["otherconnection"]).connection.tables
```