# Using ActiveRecord on Multiple Databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing a payroll system that will integrate with a pre-existing system. The original system had a master database that handled user management and some global configuration, below that there are multiple databases each identical in structure, basically each database is one companies payroll database, all these are tied to the main database because it belongs to a parent company who has many subsidiaries each with their own HR department.

What I was wondering is if there is any way that I can, based on either a cookie or another method that stores what company they wish to connect to, dynamically change the ActiveRecord's target database based on their input using a before filter?

Here's an example:

User A logs in to the site, page loads with available companies that the user has permission to access, user will then select a company, they have admin privileges in that company, they add an employee, before that action is run, rails will switch the connection to the appropriate database then add the record.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting Rails 3.1 with Multiple Databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122508/connecting-rails-3-1-with-multiple-databases)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [ActiveRecord::Base#establish_connection](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/establish_connection/class), to connect to the desired database.

You could pass the db credentials to `establish_connection` as a `Hash`

```
establish_connection(
  adapter: 'mysql2',
  encoding: 'utf8',
  pool: 5,
  username: 'me',
  password: 'mypassword'
)
```

There are more examples [here](http://pullmonkey.com/2008/4/21/ruby-on-rails-multiple-database-connections/)

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Comment: Quick question, is the database.yml loaded when `establish_connection` called? because I might have to dynamically add new database connections via a web based control panel.

Comment: You can pass the db credentials to `establish_connection` as a `Hash`

Comment: okay sweet, this should work perfectly with what I'm going to be doing, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure you can do it in run time, since the database connection is coupled to the class (model)

However, you can make different classes to be connected to different databases
I don't want to copy someone else answer, so just look at this post

[Connecting Rails 3.1 with Multiple Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122508/connecting-rails-3-1-with-multiple-databases)

and give him the credit

Good luck