# How can I configure Sidekiq against different databases?

Tags: sidekiq

I've looked at this online and I am having trouble wrapping my head around the concept.

I have multiple databases that I need users to be able to run reports against. So each report will be "registered" against one of 3 databases.

So instead of having multiple Rails applications, each with it's own Sidekiq, I want to have a single application that runs jobs against multiple databases.

I suppose it could be as simple as hijacking the database connection in the `perform` method? I would appreciate hearing about any alternative configuration anyone may have come up with or encountered.

I am running Sidekiq Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

FYI this question has nothing to do with Sidekiq.  It's an ActiveRecord concern, e.g.

[Using ActiveRecord on Multiple Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942020/using-activerecord-on-multiple-databases)