# Connecting to different databases using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

any one have any idea how can i use TNS file that are stored in oracle and have many database information to connect through my ruby test ? i want every time to connect to different data source. please help

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to connect to multiple databases using rails. All that you need is to create settings files and create appropriate models. More detailed it described there [Connecting Rails 3.1 with Multiple Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122508/connecting-rails-3-1-with-multiple-databases)