# Rails refer to 2nd DB for single table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have two MySQL databases on a single host. I want to primarily use the first database and to refer to the second database for a single, specific table. All DB calls should refer to the first DB except for calls that reference this specific table. Is there a way to either forward DB requests to another DB or to adjust the configurations in rails to accommodate this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6126706/23915

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use establish_connection in your class

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection(
      adapter: 'mysql2'
      encoding: 'utf8'
      pool: 5
      username: 'me'
      password: 'mypassword'
    )
end
```

You can find more details [here](http://pullmonkey.com/2008/4/21/ruby-on-rails-multiple-database-connections/)