# rufus-scheduler and multiple databases connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rufus-scheduler

In my rails multi-tenant application, I use multiple databases and I switch from one to another using `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(tenant_config)`, this work fine.
how to handle this multiple connections in rufus-scheduler ? Do I have to iterate connections in each scheduler ?

```
#not work
scheduler.every '1h' do
    MyModel.create(title: "test")
end
```

maybe like this :

```
scheduler.every '1h' do
    active_records_all_connections.each do
      MyModel.create(title: "test")
    end
end
```

can someone help me with a better solution or an advise.
Thx.

I use this code to manage my multiple db connections

```
module DatabaseSwitching

  def choose_database_from_tenant(tenant)
    unless defined? @@_client_database_details
      @@_client_database_details = Hash.new
    end
    if @@_client_database_details[tenant].nil?
      @@_client_database_details[tenant] = fetch_tenant_database_for tenant
    end
    connect_to_database_for @@_client_database_details[tenant]

  end

  def fetch_tenant_database_for(tenant)
    file_path = "#{Rails.root}/config/databases/database.yml"
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found') unless tenant
    tenant_db = "database_" + tenant

    if @file_to_load != File.ctime(file_path)
      @details = YAML.load_file(file_path)[tenant_db]
      @file_to_load = File.ctime(file_path)
      raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found') unless @details
    end
    @details
  end


  def connect_to_database_for(details)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(details)
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambi says:

> In my rails multi-tenant application, I use multiple databases and
>   I switch from one to another using ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(tenant_config)

So, simply do something like:

```
scheduler.every '1h' do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(tconfig0)
  MyModel.create(title: "test for tenant0")
end
scheduler.every '1h' do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(tconfig1)
  MyModel.create(title: "test for tenant1")
end
```

You switch with .establish_connection in your regular code, why not using it in your scheduled jobs?

Please note that rufus-scheduler does not give a damn about Rails or Active Record or database connections, it just uses threads to get its scheduling work done. No magic.

Answer (score 1):

I would move the database connection separation to the Models. Similar to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6126706/793330)

That way rufus scheduler doesn't need to know about the connection.

Answer (score -1):

I did not know if it's good for performance! I'd do that :

```
 # for each tenant (db connection) 
     scheduler.every '1h' do
            Tenant.each do |tconfig|
              ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(tconfig)
              MyModel.create(title: "test")
            end
        end
```

Comment: Depends on the duration of a single operation and on the number of tenants... If there are 70 tenants and a single operation runs for 1 minute... Have fun!