# Rails Migration Target Specific DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

In my rails app, I reference multiple databases. Using connection_ninja I tell models where to point, but how do I do the same for migrations?

`RAILS_ENV` doesn't work since specific migrations need to point to specific DBs

Thanks in advanced,
Justin

UPDATE--------------

I discovered `establish_connection` (basis for conn_ninja & connected to other dbs) is not honored by ActiveRecord::Migration even though the method is part of ActiveRecord::Base.

Any ideas on how to hack around this?

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveRecord::Migration` just uses `ActiveRecord::Base` so you should **hypothetically** be able to put `use_connection_ninja(:group)` in your migration

Comment: Yeah i tried that with: `require 'connection_ninja'` then `use_connection_ninja(:db_name)` but it spits back `undefined method 'use_connection_ninja' for #<ActiveRecord::Migration:0x007fa0b721d4a0>`

Comment: can you gist your stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an old one, but I struggled with this recently and finally discovered not just a hack, but an actual solution.

The trick is to use a Model connection instead of modifying the ActiveRecord::Base connection which will cause issues after the migration when schema_migrations are updated.

Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34292909/2499227