# RSpec: how to run tests on a different database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I have to migrate some data and I'd like to test some models that use a different connection, i.e. other than one defined in `database.yml` `develoment`, `test` groups.
So I added a new database connection to `database.yml`:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  user: postgres
  password:
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>

production:
  <<: *default
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>
  database: myapp_production
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>

mystore:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  host: <%= ENV['mystore_db_host']%>
  port: <%= ENV['mystore_db_port']%>
  database: <%= ENV['mystore_db_name']%>
  username: <%= ENV['mystore_db_user']%>
  password: <%= ENV['mystore_db_password']%>
```

Next, I creates a base model class in `lib/mystore_migration`  folder:

```
module MystoreMigration
  class MystoreModel < ApplicationRecord
    self.abstract_class = true
    establish_connection(:mystore)
  end
end
```

Other model classes used by the rake task inherit the above `MystoreMigration` class.

Next, when I just tried to initialize one of the models that use `mystore` connection in RSpec test file:

```
MystoreMigration::ShopInfo.new(
      address: Faker::Address.street_address,
      address2: Faker::Address.street_name,
...
)
```

and run it, it failed:

```
OCIError:
  ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified
```

It seems like RSpec tried to use another settings/database or whatever instead of the one I defined with `establish_connection(:mystore)`.

If I add `unless Rails.env.test?` condition to `establish_connection`:

```
module MystoreMigration
  class MystoreModel < ApplicationRecord
    self.abstract_class = true
    establish_connection(:mystore) unless Rails.env.test?
  end
end
```

the error message is different and says it can'd set up relations:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "STORE_INFO" does not exist
       LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"STORE_INFO"'::regclass
```

As you see, in the first case, it tried to connect to Oracle database what is correct but it failed. In the second case it tried to connect to Postgresql database (wrong, as it is used in other environments than `mystore`).

If I run a rake task that uses `mystore` connection, it works, - running tests- fails. What's wrong with that ?

I'm using `Rails 5.2.0`, `ruby 2.5.0`, macOS.
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `unless Rails.env.test?` at `establish_connection`!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like when running tests, Rails will query the database defined in `test` group in `database.yml`, - in my case it is `myapp_test`. But when querying the models using `mystore` connection, it will not find the corresponding tables, because there is no database connection defined for those models in `test` environment. It means that the only solution is to mock all the database requests for the models that use `mystore` connection.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I think it can help someone that ends up here searching for an answer. I'm in `RoR 5.2.2`.

In my case when I did `establish_connection` to another database in a model it wasn't working in env `test`, but in other environments.

`Alt 1.` This wasn't working in `test` env

```rb
class AnotherConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection(:another_db)
end
```

`Alt 2.` I came up with this solution, inspired [from this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15139784/1526010)

```rb
class AnotherConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  class << self
    def connection
      @connection_x ||=
        establish_connection(:another_db).connection
    end
  end
end
```

The `@connection_x` is because I don't want to interfere with any existing (class) instance variables in RoR.

In both cases `AnotherConnection.connection_config` was showing the "other database", but in `Alt 1.` it was still using the "main" database when doing queries. And this was only a problem in `test` (with `RSpec`). In `development` env both alternatives work.