# Paperclip::Attachment - undefined method `attach'. Asset Migration Rake Task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rails-migrations, rails-activestorage

I am currently migrating from Paperclip to Active Storage using [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/MIGRATING.md) tutorial, as well as referencing the official [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/active_storage_overview.html).

Current roadblock is the rake task for [migrating my assets](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/MIGRATING.md#moving-files-on-a-remote-host-s3-azure-storage-gcs-etc).

This is the content of my `lib/tasks/migrate_paperclip_assets.rake` file:

```
desc 'Generates file names on AWS S3 and places them in their proper structure'
namespace :posts do
  task migrate_to_active_storage: :environment do
    Post.where.not(image_file_name: nil).find_each do |post|
      img_filename = post.image_file_name
      ext = File.extname(img_filename)

      image_url =
      "https://#{Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws,
      :bucket_name)}/#{Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws,
      :host_name)}/posts/images/000/000/#{post.id}/original/#{img_filename}"
      puts image_url
      post.image.attach(io: open(image_url),
                            filename: post.image_file_name,
                            content_type: post.image_content_type)
    end
  end
end
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `attach' for #<Paperclip::Attachment:0x00000003170090> 
[...]
```

On the Rails migration guide, it clearly states to use this method attach [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-file-io-objects) in the same format as I have done - not sure why this spews an error. I know for sure that the url works and I have successfully attempted to download the images.

Here are things I have tried that did not work:

1. Attempted [this accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482220/rails-migration-complains-about-undefined-method-attachment-using-paperclip).
2. The closest thing to attach I saw from [the docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/Attachment) was `assign` method. But there were no handlers for dealing with the image file.
3. I also have tried downloading the files in the same directory and uploading them using the same `post.image.attach`.

Even though the [Paperclip Attachment Class](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb) itself does not have an `attach` method defined, there are a good number of repos on GitHub with code having similar format:
`user.avatar.attach(io: open(avatar_url), filename: user.avatar_file_name)`.

This is the content of my `app/models/post.rb` file:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :dislikes, dependent: :destroy
    attr_accessor :uploaded_image_for_io_adapters, :file_name, :top_text, :bot_text


    has_attached_file :image  

  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
  validates_attachment :image, presence: true
  validates_presence_of :poster
    validates_presence_of :description
    validates :user, presence: true
    validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

Lost and confused, if you could suggest an alternative to bypass having to use this `attach` method, or give me pointers as to what it is I might be doing wrong that would be great.

For context, Ruby version: 2.4.1, Rails: 5.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the solution is in the [documentation you have shared](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/MIGRATING.md#moving-files-on-a-remote-host-s3-azure-storage-gcs-etc).

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  # New ActiveStorage declaration
  has_one_attached :logo

  # Old Paperclip config
  # must be removed BEFORE to running the rake task so that
  # all of the new ActiveStorage goodness can be used when
  # calling organization.logo
  has_attached_file :logo,
                    path: "/organizations/:id/:basename_:style.:extension",
                    default_url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxx/organizations/missing_:style.jpg",
                    default_style: :normal,
                    styles: { thumb: "64x64#", normal: "400x400>" },
                    convert_options: { thumb: "-quality 100 -strip", normal: "-quality 75 -strip" }
end
```

It looks like the `has_attached_file` has to be replaced by `has_one_attached`.

Otherwise, `image` will use Paperclip instead of ActiveStorage (which has `attach` method).

Comment: +@MrShemek I am so dumb. I can't believe myself. +1

Comment: Well, that's why they should put it exactly in the migration steps, not in the code comment :)