# How to run migration to a specific database when application uses multiple databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, database-migration

My application is connected **two databases** one primary, and another for reporting purpose, Now I want to to run a migration on reporting database, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a custom rake task. Checkout this link: 
[ActiveRecord multiple dbs](http://excid3.com/blog/rails-activerecord-multiple-databases-and-migrations/).

This might be helpful too; provides alternative methods:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404620](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404620/using-rails-migration-on-different-database-than-standard-production-or-devel)